# Kotlin Android-devops

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

heelo have 2 activities second activity it's 3 textview with name : (1textview with check box choise) text Spider man)  second activty  (2textview and check box choise with text batman), (3textview with check box choise) with text Deutschland). this  informaton i should send to main activity ( main Activity has 3 Text view ) and for example I'm choised in second activity textview movie Spider man with chek box , this textView spider man should show in main activity Spider Man . or I'm Choised in second Activity Batman textview , this text view Batman should to show in Main Activity word BAtman help me please im beginner

I dont understand Java please write only By Kotlin , I don't know Java

this is my code from second Activity

```
class MoviesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies)

    val textu = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textu)
    val chbt = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.chbt)

    val textti = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textti)
    val chbLn = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.chbLn)

    val texth = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texth)
    val chbbt = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.chbbt)

    val btback = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btback)


    btback.setOnClickListener {
        val tv1 = textu.text.toString()
        val cb1 = chbt.isChecked
        val tv2 = textti.text.toString()
        val cb2 = chbLn.isChecked
        val tv3 = texth.text.toString()
        val cb3 = chbbt.isChecked

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

        intent.putExtra("tv1", tv1)
        intent.putExtra("cb1 ", cb1)
        intent.putExtra("tv2 ", tv2)
        intent.putExtra("cb2 ", cb2)
        intent.putExtra("tv3 ", tv3)
        intent.putExtra("cb3 ", cb3)


        // startActivity(intent)

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent)
        finish()
    }

}
```

}

this is from Main Activty

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val texttv1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texttv1)
    val  texttv2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texttv2)
    val  texttv3 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texttv3)
    val  texttv4 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texttv4)
    val  texttv5 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texttv5)
    val  texttv6 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texttv6)



    val btnpage = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnpage)


    btnpage.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MoviesActivity::class.java)


        startActivityForResult(intent, 1)

        



    }

    val etData1 = intent.getStringExtra("tvinf")
    val chBox1 =  intent.getBooleanExtra("cb1",true)

    val etData2 = intent.getStringExtra("tv2")
    val chBox2 =  intent.getBooleanExtra("cb2",true)

    val etData3 = intent.getStringExtra("tv3")
    val chBox3 =  intent.getBooleanExtra("cb3",true)

    texttv1.text = etData1

    if (chBox1) {

        texttv2.text = "not choised"
    }
    else { texttv2.text = "choised"

    }

    texttv3.text = etData2

    if (chBox2) {

        texttv4.text = "not choised"
    }
    else { texttv4.text = "choised"

    }

    texttv5.text = etData3


    if (chBox3) {

        texttv6.text = "not choised"
    }
    else { texttv6.text = "choised"

    }


































}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a method onCheckChangedListener

you should use a local variable in your class

```
var userAnswer;
override fun onCreate(){
...//do your things
...//you don't actually need to use text, check box has it's own text,so
...//in kotlin you don't need findViewById as well, you can simple use id :P
....//ex
textu.text = 'Your text'
textu.onText.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                userAnswer = textu.text;
            }

//and now, you only need to return the user's answer

btback.setOnClickListener {
   
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

    intent.putExtra("user_answer", userAnswer)

    startActivity(intent)
}
```

And now in your main activity

```
userAnswer = intent.getStringExtra("user_answer")
```

Hope,i helped you mate